# I am trying to write stuff connected with Lagrange's four-square theorem, how can I optimize my code, because it can't pass all the tests on of time

Tags: python-3.x, performance, math, optimization

The task is: Given a positive integer n, find the number of ordered tuples (a, b, c, d, e) over non-negative integers for which a² + b² + c² + d² = n and b + 3c + 5d = e².

```
n = int(input())
    count = 0
    for e in range(3 * math.floor(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(n))) + 2):
        for c in range(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
            for b in range(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
                if (e**2-b-3*c)/5 == int((e**2-b-3*c)/5) and (e**2-b-3*c) >= 0:
                    for a in range(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
                        if a**2 +(26*b**2+6*b*c-2*e**2*b+34*c**2-6*e**2*c+e**4)/25 == n:
                            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: Some idea for improvements: don't have the main loop over `e`, especially not when the range-formula doesn't seem to be correct. Also, working with float divisions in `(e**2-b-3*c)/5 == int((e**2-b-3*c)/5)` is prone to floating-point approximations; `(e**2-b-3*c) % 5 == 0` seems less dangerous. Even better could be to calculate `b = e**2-5*d-3*c` without needing a division.  For `a` no loop is needed, just test whether `n - b**2 - c**2 - d**2` is a square.

Comment: If you have working code and what you seek is to make it "better". You should check out : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank U, indeed I had unnecessary  loop, by the way, I am very new in coding, don't judge strictly)
just got rid of a loop and changed if as you said, and everything worked fine: 10 out of 10 tests!
                `if n - (26*b**2+6*b*c-2*e**2*b+34*c**2-6*e**2*c+e**4)/25 >= 0 and math.sqrt(n - (26*b**2+6*b*c-2*e**2*b+34*c**2-6*e**2*c+e**4)/25) == int(math.sqrt(n - (26*b**2+6*b*c-2*e**2*b+34*c**2-6*e**2*c+e**4)/25)) :`